# Stack Exchange iOS app crashes when viewing a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

The Stack Exchange iOS app keeps crashing whenever I try to view this question:

[add width to an element with js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452100/add-width-to-an-element-with-js)

Why does it happen? Am I the only one having this problem?

Comment: Your iOS app? Or the Stack Exchange iOS app? The former would be off-topic.

Comment: StackExchange iOS app, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue seems to be fixed in the beta with version 1.3.2.216. There seems to be a recent fix in loading questions which might have fixed this issue too.

At least, I can't reproduce this in the mentioned beta version.

Comment: I have 1.3.1 version. Its still crashing. No update is showing up on AppStore.

Comment: It is the *beta* I am using. You can't download it from the app store.

Comment: Where do you get beta from?

Comment: You have to be invited.

Comment: @Mustaghees is the problem solved?

Comment: yes it is now solved.